# Json with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following data:

```
d = "{\"key_1": \" val_1\", \"key_2\": \"val_2\"}{\"key_3\": \" val_3\", \"key_4\": \"val_4\"}"
```

which I would like to translate to a list of dictionary, e.g.

```
d_list = [{\"key_1": \" val_1\", \"key_2\": \"val_2\"}, {\"key_3\": \" val_3\", \"key_4\": \"val_4\"}]
```

1. json.loads(d) gives me error of type: raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a missing slash escaping the quote after `key_1`?  With that it's at least just weird JSON-concatenation.  Without it it's not even valid Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`JSONDecoder`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) and its `raw_decode()` method to accomplish this.  `raw_decode()` will read a complete JSON object, and return a tuple whose first member is the object, and whose second is the offset into the string where the decoder stopped reading.

Basically, you need to read one object, then store it in an array, then read the next object from the string, and so on until you are at the end of the string.  Like this:

```
import json

def read_json_objects(data):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    offset = 0

    while offset < len(data):
        item = decoder.raw_decode(data[offset:])

        yield item[0]
        offset += item[1]

d = '{"key_1": " val_1", "key_2": "val_2"}{"key_3": " val_3", "key_4": "val_4"}'

print json.dumps(list(read_json_objects(d)))
```

Which will output this:

```
[{"key_1": " val_1", "key_2": "val_2"}, {"key_4": "val_4", "key_3": " val_3"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON, you should try adding a comma between two objects.
`d = "{\"key_1": \" val_1\", \"key_2\": \"val_2\"}, {\"key_3\": \" val_3\", \"key_4\": \"val_4\"}"`

Comment: The comma still won't make it valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issues where i got `{key1:val1, key2:val2}{key1:val1, key2:val2}`. Only way i could fix it was be following:

```
def json_parser(msg):
    msg=msg.split("{")
    for i in msg:
        L=i.split("}")
        msg_new={}
        for j in L:
            if j:
                LL=j.split(",")
                for l in LL:
                    msg_new[string.strip(l.split(":")[0]).replace('"','')]=string.strip(l.split(":")[1]).replace('"','')
        return msg_new
```

where....

```
try:
                        data_loaded=json.loads(data)
                    except:
                        data_loaded=json_parser(str(data))
```

I tried many attempts but this one could handle loads of `{..}{..}{..}` examples.